# How to use GUI values in 'external' recursive function

Tags: java, user-interface

I am hoping my terminology in the question made some sense, I am still getting the hang of it and if it's not right then I apologize.

So, first off, I made my very second recursive function the other day (I hope!) and it works all fine and dandy. It outputs "5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1" so just a simple factorial one.

```
 public class Main {

    public static String fact(int n) {
        if(n == 1){ //see how I made n equaled to 1? I'd like to change that to whatever value the user of the program inputs, so for ex...it could be 8
            return "1";
        }
        return n + " x " + (fact(n-1)); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fact(5)); 
       //so if it was 8 it would output "8 x 7 x 6 x ...etc. x 1"
    }

 }

private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //ok Button

        ItsATextField.setText(fact(5)); //outputs on GUI

}
```

However I have moved this code and incorporated into a program that uses a GUI and made it output the answer in a textField. Now, the function starts off at '5', but I would like to change it to value 'n' (being a value the user of the program enters) so I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Would I have to create a class under 'public class MyProgram'? And grab the entered value using getText in that class?

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated! =)

Comment: If my question isn't thorough, please comment and I'll change it as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with :

```
if (n==1) {
    return 1;
}
```

it's the "stop condition" of the recursion. Don't change it.

If you want to compute fact(aValue), just call fact with 'aValue' as parameter...
If you have a JTextField (let's call it theJTextField) :
`ItsATextField.setText(Main.fact(Integer.parse(theJTextField.getText())));`

Comment: Awesome, so how how I use the getText now I throw it in the function so it knows to start at 'n' value and not always at 5 anymore?

Comment: Its not so much as a problem but a lack of knowledge. I'll update my question in 30 seconds to help you understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I updated my answer. But the main method of the class is just for test or you want to create some GUI from this method ? Have a look at JFrame.